# Anonymous User Identity in Firebase and Android

Tags: android, firebase

Im trying to work out some further issues with Firebase / Android.

The link here, https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info shows the concept of Anonymous User Identity and it's consistent Identity between devices - ie Google Home *should* be the same as an Android device.

Yet no joy. The two User ID's returned, one from `FirebaseUser.getUid()` on Android, and the other from `app.getUser().userId` are not the same.

Any thoughts on why this would be when their own documentation says it should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that these [requirements](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) are met?

- The user's Google account is the same on both devices.
- The user registered their voice on Google Home
- The user's voice is matched on the Google Home.

Comment: Well I haven't got a lot to go on unfortunately. However requesting user permissions, I get my name back as a Display Name, so that looks OK. I can presume it's me. It should be me logged on as both devices. Only thing I can think of is if it's because Im logged onto the Sandbox mode and getting a stupid userId back in firebase.